# How to write text below checked textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my HTML and jQuery code. The code is working good but the problem is when I click on one checkbox, the text "FINISHED" becomes visible below all the checkboxes instead of that one only.

My html code is:

```js
$('.label__checkbox').click(function() {
  if ($(".label__checkbox").is(':checked')) {
    $(".finish").css("display", "block");
  } else {
    $(".finish").css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="center">
  <label class="label">
        <input  class="label__checkbox" type="checkbox" />
        <span class="label__text">
          <span class="label__check">
            <i class="fa fa-check icon"></i>
          </span>
        </span>
      </label>
  <span class="finish">FINISHED</span>
</div>
<div class="center">
  <label class="label">
        <input  class="label__checkbox" type="checkbox" />
        <span class="label__text">
          <span class="label__check">
            <i class="fa fa-check icon"></i>
          </span>
        </span>
      </label>
  <span class="finish">FINISHED</span>
</div>
<div class="center">
  <label class="label">
        <input  class="label__checkbox" type="checkbox" />
        <span class="label__text">
          <span class="label__check">
            <i class="fa fa-check icon"></i>
          </span>
        </span>
      </label>
  <span class="finish">FINISHED</span>
</div>
<div class="center">
  <label class="label">
        <input  class="label__checkbox" type="checkbox" />
        <span class="label__text">
          <span class="label__check">
            <i class="fa fa-check icon"></i>
          </span>
        </span>
      </label>
  <span class="finish">FINISHED</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Add an id tag to the checkbox you want to target with your code, and use the #id in jQuery to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use DOM traversal method to target them in the current element context i.e. `this`

`.closest()` can be use to traverse up to `label` then use `.next()` to target the `<span>`

```js
$('.label__checkbox').change(function() {
  var finish = $(this).closest('.label').next(".finish");
  //var finish = $(this).closest('.center').find(".finish");
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    finish.css("display", "block");
  } else {
    finish.css("display", "none");
  }
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center">
  <label class="label">
    <input  class="label__checkbox" type="checkbox" />
    <span class="label__text">
      <span class="label__check">
        <i class="fa fa-check icon"></i>
      </span>
    </span>
  </label>
  <span class="finish">FINISHED</span>
</div>
<div class="center">
  <label class="label">
    <input  class="label__checkbox" type="checkbox" />
    <span class="label__text">
      <span class="label__check">
        <i class="fa fa-check icon"></i>
      </span>
    </span>
  </label>
  <span class="finish">FINISHED</span>
</div>
```